# what is the root of WAMP for putting crossDomain.xml file

Tags: php, wamp

I following a [tutorial](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores) it said

> Upload this(cross domain xml) file to the root of your web server.

crossDomain.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

SO where ot put this file into WAMP?
in WAMP/WWW

or

in WAMP/MYWEBSITE

or else

I tried in both folder and i failed to access it through my code.

Answer (score 0):

it's in your apache config file.
here is /var/www
    sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>
> ```
>         DocumentRoot /var/www
>         <Directory />
>                 Options FollowSymLinks
>                 AllowOverride None
>         </Directory>
>         <Directory /var/www/>
>                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>                 AllowOverride None
>                 Order allow,deny
>                 allow from all
>         </Directory>
> ```

Comment: you mean config file in apache folder?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan this is the configment of apache server on ubuntu. for other OS you can google it